# Hibernate -- @Column.unique for non-key fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa

This is to look for verification rather than a question:

`@Column.unique` of Hibernate checks & ensures the uniqueness of the column entries at the JPA level. 
The column here can be any column and not necessarily a key or a part of a composite key.

`@Column.unique` on a **non-key** field is working fine-- checking the field value and not inserting it if it already is in the table which is what i expect. 
Hibernate is adding an index to the column upon the annotation `@Column(unique=true)` -- which is also fine.

However, `@Column.unique` [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#unique%28%29) reads like it is for the key fields.

```
(Optional) Whether the property is a unique key. This is a shortcut for the UniqueConstraint annotation at the table level and is useful for when the unique key constraint is only a single field. This constraint applies in addition to any constraint entailed by primary key mapping and to constraints specified at the table level.
```

I'm wondering whether i'm missing something here-- whether i'd run into troubles out of this later on.

ps: i'm aware that using the unique constraint of hibernate 
is making sure of the uniqueness of the column entries 
*at the JPA level*-- and doesn't ensure it down below in the database itself. 
That's not an issue here.

pps; i'm also aware of the use of `@UniqueConstraint` property within `@Table` as an alternative to this. 
That's not what i'm after either. it's doing the same thing at the table level.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `unique` attribute of `javax.persistence.Column` annotation is used during generation of DDL.

It means, that if you attempt to create database schema from your mapped classes, then everywhere this attribute is present and set to true, unique constraint will be added to appropriate column in database.

However, according to JPA spec it does not have any impact during runtime of your application.